# What are the differences between the two Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 7.0" models?

Tags: hardware, multi-user, samsung-galaxy-tab-4

I have just got a new Samsung GALAXY Tab 4 7.0" (SM-T230NU).

What is the difference (or improvements) between the 'stock' SM-T230 model GALAXY Tab 4 7.0" and the 'newer' SM-T230NU, recently released for US/Canada and in EU?

Are there also other NU devices? I have also seen references to the GALAXY Tab 4 10.1" as SM-T530NU.

---

I have found [one possible issue](http://www.thegalaxytabforum.com/index.php?/topic/26034-multi-user-mode-not-available/), with the SM-T230 *not having* multi-user mode:

> The multi users setting is not available. According to the manual it should be at settings => General => Users.

(My device does have multi-user capability)

---

I also saw a reference to the two different models [on XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2778374):

> Do make sure your tablet is a T230NU model and not just a T230
>   model.

---

**UPDATE: 04-Jul-2014**

There are **three** variants: T230, T230NT, T230NU

from: [Samsung T230 | T230NT | T230NU Galaxy Tab 4 7.0 WiFi Firmwares](http://www.tsar3000.com/Joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1518%3asamsung-sm-t230-t230nu-galaxy-tab4-7.0-wifi-firmwares&catid=55%3asamsung&Itemid=82)

Answer (score 0):

According to other reviews, the plain SM-T230 does not support OTG, 
but the SM-T237p does.

I remember how disappointed I was to find this with my SM-T210R.

Answer (score -1):

SM-T230nu has an IR remote, while a simple tab 4 (SM-T230) doesn't have one.

Comment: The **SM-T230NU** (Tab4 7.0) is a *regional* model, for North America (US/Canada). I can confirm it *DOES* have an IR 'port', whereas the **SM-T330** (Tab4 8.0) does *NOT*. I have yet to examine an *international* model **SM-T230** (Tab4 7.0).

Comment: *Is there anything to suggest that is the ONLY difference?*